# WordCloud changes behaviour between v11 and v13

Tags: word-cloud

The behaviour with default settings hasn't changed, but when I add **WordOrientation** in v13 words appear smaller and way more apart, whereas in v11 they nicely fill the image.

```
data = EntityValue[CountryData[], {"Name", "Population"}];
WordCloud[data, WordOrientation -> {{-Pi/3, Pi/6}}]
```

Version 11 rendering:
[[image: Version 11 rendering][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ONtm.png)

Version 13 rendering:
[image: Version 13 rendering]

Is there a setting for v13 to get the same result as under v11? **FontSize** or **WordSpacings** don't seem to have any effect.

**Note (2023-08-19)**
Still not fixed in v13.3.

Comment: I also noticed, plating with that code in the cloud, that `WordOrientation -> "Random"` also doesn't seem to work: all words are horizontal in the result. Odd.

Comment: @Marco -- For me this works correctly in both v11 and v13.

Comment: v12.2.0 on Win7-x64 renders the wordclouds correctly.

Comment: The output on Linux 13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) is the same as OP. Perhaps, file a support ticket?